# NetBeans no resalta la llave correspondiente { }

Tags: netbeans

Antes, en *NetBeans*, dentro del editor de código, al posicionar el cursor de inserción en la llave de inicio `{` o de fin `}` de una función (`function`) o método, esta llave se colocaba en un color amarillo, que me servia para ver cual llave correspondía a la señalada.  Es decir, se estaba en una llave de apertura `{`, sin importar cuantos pares de llaves le seguían en el código, solo estaba en amarillo también la `}` que correspondía a la primera. Ahora esto dejó de funcionar.

Si saben como reactivar esa funciona se los agradecería.

Comment: En si no es una pregunta propia sobre programación, quizás en este [enlace](https://netbeans.org/kb/index.html) encuentres información.

Comment: @SilvestreSilva Las preguntas sobre "herramientas de software comunmente empleadas por programadores" son explícitamente [on-topic](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el menú prinicpal de NetBeans debes ir a *Tools/Options/Fonts & Colors/highlighting*. Su equivalente en español, que dado que no lo utilizo, no estoy seguro de cuál es, pero debiera ser algo como *Herramients/Opciones/Fuentes y colores/resaltado*.

Allí busca las opciones que inicien con *Braces matching*.

Adjunto una imagen para mejor referencia.

[image: NetBeans opciones]

Comment: MIL GRACIAS, EL PROBLEMA SE ME ARREGLO CUANDO RESETEE EL NETBEAN PERO TU AYUDA ES VALIOSA.